# Is it possible to use multiple 'MTAudioProcessingTap's?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

In my iOS app, I'm using `AVFoundation`'s AVComposition to create a video, with multiple audio tracks. I am trying to let the user see the volume/power-level for each audio-track. I've successfully implemented this for one track, but as soon as I try to use a second `MTAudioProcessingTap`, it fails with OSError `-12780`. In fact, if I use a processingTap and then go 'back' - deallocating the entire view controller, and re-opening that particular window, it won't even attach the processingTap again, even if the first `AVPlayer` playing the composition has been deallocated. To solve this, I found out from searching that I have to manually release it and clearing out the audioMix for the player, but that's not my problem now. Now, I can't clear out the other processingTap, I need them both!

I'm not completely sure what the `MTAudioProcessingTap` actually is, as it is the single least documented piece of code ever to come out of the Apple dev-team, by far. I've watched the WWDC, and gone through the iPad-sample-project they have made, but I can't figure out how to have two taps running.

I figured I might not actually need two taps, but maybe use one to handle more than one audioTrack, however if I somehow manage to use the same tap for two AudioTracks, I wouldn't know how to tell the taps apart in the static callbacks. Is there perhaps another way to monitor audio-levels from an `AVComposition` playing in an `AVPlayer`, or is there a way like this?